# Best Way to join 1 to many tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables. First one is name of all members and second is all projects and its team members of different roles.

Table 1 : [members] id, name

Table 2 : [projects] id, proj_name, sponsor (fk1_tbl_1), proj_mgr(fk2_tbl_1) , proj_co (fk3_tbl_1)

I created a query to show the project name and names of all project roles.

I am doing three joins with two sub-queries in order to achieve this.

I want to know if there is better ways to do this (in pure sql, NOT script languages like pl/sql).

```
select f.proj_name, f.proj_sponsor, f.proj_mgr, e.name proj_co
from 
    name e,
    (
        select 
            d.proj_name, d.proj_sponsor, c.name proj_mgr, d.proj_co
        from 
            members c,
        (
            select 
                b.proj_name, a.name proj_sponsor, b.proj_mgr mgr, b.proj_co co 
            from 
                members a, projects b 
            where 
                b.sponsor = a.id
        ) d
        where 
            c.id = d.mgr
    ) f
where 
    e.id = f.proj_co
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data? I believe that I have an idea, but I would need to see your desired results from the data you have to ensure that it's relevant.

Comment: @SeanBrookins Thanks for the response. Gordon's provided the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `join` and `join` again:

```
select p.*, ms.name as sponsor, mm.name as manager, mc.name as co_name
from projects p left join
     members ms
     on p.sponsor = ms.id left join
     members mm
     on p.manager = mm.id left join
     members mo
     on p.proj_co = mo.id;
```

Notes:

- This uses `left join` in case any values are missing.  The project will still be returned.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Use meaningful table aliases, rather than arbitrary letters.

Comment: I think you wanted `mm.name as manager` not `ms.name as manager`

Comment: @user1941319, the solution that Gordon is applying here is joining to the source table repeatedly, one time for each foreign key relationship. This pattern comes up over and over again, for instance when a fact table contains many dates that reference back to a date dimension. By using good, meaningful table aliases, it helps keep the SELECT list clear as far as which instance of the source table you're referencing with each element.

Comment: Thanks everyone one for the advise.